# Restarting systemd service on dependency failure

Tags: systemd

What's the right approach to handle restarting a service in case one of its dependencies fails on startup (but succeeds after retry).

Here's a contrived repro to make the problem clearer.

**a.service** (simulates failure on first try and success on second try)

```
[Unit]
Description=A

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -x -c "[ -f /tmp/success ] || (touch /tmp/success && sleep 10)"
ExecStart=/bin/true
TimeoutStartSec=5
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

**b.service** (trivially succeeds after A starts)

```
[Unit]
Description=B
After=a.service
Requires=a.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
```

Let's start b:

```
# systemctl start b
A dependency job for b.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

Logs:

```
Jun 30 21:34:54 debug systemd[1]: Starting A...
Jun 30 21:34:54 debug sh[1308]: + '[' -f /tmp/success ']'
Jun 30 21:34:54 debug sh[1308]: + touch /tmp/success
Jun 30 21:34:54 debug sh[1308]: + sleep 10
Jun 30 21:34:59 debug systemd[1]: a.service start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
Jun 30 21:34:59 debug systemd[1]: Failed to start A.
Jun 30 21:34:59 debug systemd[1]: Dependency failed for B.
Jun 30 21:34:59 debug systemd[1]: Job b.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 30 21:34:59 debug systemd[1]: Unit a.service entered failed state.
Jun 30 21:34:59 debug systemd[1]: a.service failed.
Jun 30 21:35:04 debug systemd[1]: a.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 30 21:35:04 debug systemd[1]: Starting A...
Jun 30 21:35:04 debug systemd[1]: Started A.
Jun 30 21:35:04 debug sh[1314]: + '[' -f /tmp/success ']'
```

A has been successfully started but B is left in a failed state and won't retry.

**EDIT**

I added the following to both services and now B successfully starts when A starts, but I can't explain why.

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Why would this affect the relationship between A and B?

**EDIT2**

Above "fix" doesn't work in systemd 220.

**systemd 219 debug logs**

```
systemd219 systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job b.service/start/replace
systemd219 systemd[1]: Installed new job b.service/start as 3454
systemd219 systemd[1]: Installed new job a.service/start as 3455
systemd219 systemd[1]: Enqueued job b.service/start as 3454
systemd219 systemd[1]: About to execute: /bin/sh -x -c '[ -f /tmp/success ] || (touch oldcoreos
systemd219 systemd[1]: Forked /bin/sh as 1502
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed dead -> start-pre
systemd219 systemd[1]: Starting A...
systemd219 systemd[1502]: Executing: /bin/sh -x -c '[ -f /tmp/success ] || (touch /tmpoldcoreos
systemd219 sh[1502]: + '[' -f /tmp/success ']'
systemd219 sh[1502]: + touch /tmp/success
systemd219 sh[1502]: + sleep 10
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed start-pre -> final-sigterm
systemd219 systemd[1]: Child 1502 belongs to a.service
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service: control process exited, code=killed status=15
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service got final SIGCHLD for state final-sigterm
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed final-sigterm -> failed
systemd219 systemd[1]: Job a.service/start finished, result=failed
systemd219 systemd[1]: Failed to start A.
systemd219 systemd[1]: Job b.service/start finished, result=dependency
systemd219 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for B.
systemd219 systemd[1]: Job b.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
systemd219 systemd[1]: Unit a.service entered failed state.
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service failed.
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed failed -> auto-restart
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
systemd219 systemd[1]: Trying to enqueue job a.service/restart/fail
systemd219 systemd[1]: Installed new job a.service/restart as 3718
systemd219 systemd[1]: Installed new job b.service/restart as 3803
systemd219 systemd[1]: Enqueued job a.service/restart as 3718
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service scheduled restart job.
systemd219 systemd[1]: Job b.service/restart finished, result=done
systemd219 systemd[1]: Converting job b.service/restart -> b.service/start
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed auto-restart -> dead
systemd219 systemd[1]: Job a.service/restart finished, result=done
systemd219 systemd[1]: Converting job a.service/restart -> a.service/start
systemd219 systemd[1]: About to execute: /bin/sh -x -c '[ -f /tmp/success ] || (touch oldcoreos
systemd219 systemd[1]: Forked /bin/sh as 1558
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed dead -> start-pre
systemd219 systemd[1]: Starting A...
systemd219 systemd[1]: Child 1558 belongs to a.service
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service: control process exited, code=exited status=0
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service got final SIGCHLD for state start-pre
systemd219 systemd[1]: About to execute: /bin/true
systemd219 systemd[1]: Forked /bin/true as 1561
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed start-pre -> running
systemd219 systemd[1]: Job a.service/start finished, result=done
systemd219 systemd[1]: Started A.
systemd219 systemd[1]: Child 1561 belongs to a.service
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service changed running -> exited
systemd219 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd219 systemd[1]: About to execute: /bin/true
systemd219 systemd[1]: Forked /bin/true as 1563
systemd219 systemd[1]: b.service changed dead -> running
systemd219 systemd[1]: Job b.service/start finished, result=done
systemd219 systemd[1]: Started B.
systemd219 systemd[1]: Starting B...
systemd219 systemd[1]: Child 1563 belongs to b.service
systemd219 systemd[1]: b.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd219 systemd[1]: b.service changed running -> exited
systemd219 systemd[1]: b.service: cgroup is empty
systemd219 sh[1558]: + '[' -f /tmp/success ']'
```

**systemd 220 debug logs**

```
systemd220 systemd[1]: b.service: Trying to enqueue job b.service/start/replace
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Installed new job a.service/start as 4846
systemd220 systemd[1]: b.service: Installed new job b.service/start as 4761
systemd220 systemd[1]: b.service: Enqueued job b.service/start as 4761
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: About to execute: /bin/sh -x -c '[ -f /tmp/success ] || (touch /tmp/success && sleep 10)'
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Forked /bin/sh as 2032
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed dead -> start-pre
systemd220 systemd[1]: Starting A...
systemd220 systemd[2032]: a.service: Executing: /bin/sh -x -c '[ -f /tmp/success ] || (touch /tmp/success && sleep 10)'
systemd220 sh[2032]: + '[' -f /tmp/success ']'
systemd220 sh[2032]: + touch /tmp/success
systemd220 sh[2032]: + sleep 10
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed start-pre -> final-sigterm
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Child 2032 belongs to a.service
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Control process exited, code=killed status=15
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Got final SIGCHLD for state final-sigterm.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed final-sigterm -> failed
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Job a.service/start finished, result=failed
systemd220 systemd[1]: Failed to start A.
systemd220 systemd[1]: b.service: Job b.service/start finished, result=dependency
systemd220 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for B.
systemd220 systemd[1]: b.service: Job b.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed failed -> auto-restart
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Failed to send unit change signal for a.service: Transport endpoint is not connected
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Trying to enqueue job a.service/restart/fail
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Installed new job a.service/restart as 5190
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Enqueued job a.service/restart as 5190
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Scheduled restart job.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed auto-restart -> dead
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Job a.service/restart finished, result=done
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Converting job a.service/restart -> a.service/start
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: About to execute: /bin/sh -x -c '[ -f /tmp/success ] || (touch /tmp/success && sleep 10)'
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Forked /bin/sh as 2132
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed dead -> start-pre
systemd220 systemd[1]: Starting A...
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Child 2132 belongs to a.service
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=0
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Got final SIGCHLD for state start-pre.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: About to execute: /bin/true
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Forked /bin/true as 2136
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed start-pre -> running
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Job a.service/start finished, result=done
systemd220 systemd[1]: Started A.
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Child 2136 belongs to a.service
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: Changed running -> exited
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd220 systemd[1]: a.service: cgroup is empty
systemd220 sh[2132]: + '[' -f /tmp/success ']'
```

Comment: There is an upstream systemd issue tracking this: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1312

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'll try to summarize my findings for this issue in case someone comes across this as information on this topic is scant.

- `Restart=on-failure` only applies to process failures (does not apply to failure due to dependency failures)
- The fact that dependent failed units get restarted under certain conditions when a dependency successfully restart was a bug in systemd < 220:
  http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2015-July/033513.html
- If there's even a small chance that a dependency might fail on start and you care about resiliency, don't use `Before`/`After` and instead perform a check on some artifact that the dependency produces

e.g.

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/test -f /some/thing
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
```

You could even use `systemctl is-active <dependecy>`.

Very hacky, but I haven't found any better options.

In my opinion, not having a way to handle dependency failures is a flaw in systemd.

Comment: Yes, not to mention not having a retry for mount points which Leonard poetring doesn't want to implement: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4468

Comment: This issue is tracked in systemd issue 1312: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1312

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the sort of thing that could be scripted and put into a cronjob pretty easily.  The basic logic would go something like this

1. check to see if both service a and b as well as dependencies are running/in a valid state.  You will know the best way to check if everything is working correctly
2. If everything is working correctly do nothing or log that everything is working.  Logging has the advantage of allowing you to look for the previous log entry.
3. If something is broken restart the services and jump back to the beginning of the script where the service and dependency status check occurs.  Jump should only occur if you are confident in the restart of services and dependencies will have a high likelihood of working, otherwise there is the potential for a loop.
4. Let cron run the script again in a little while

Once the script is set cron is a good place to test it, if cron is inefficient the script would be a good starting place for attempting to write a low level system service that can check the status of some other services and restart them as necessary.  Depending on the amount of effort you want to invest the script could probably even be setup to email you based on the results(unless of course the services in questions are the network services).

Comment: This cronjob of stuff should be rather done in the process/service manager, otherwise you'll be going back to SVR4 methods, which systemd attempts to *not* do...

Answer (score 0):

`After` and `Before` only set the order that services will be started in, your service files say "If A and B will be started then A must be started before B".

`Requires` means if this service is to be started, that service must be started first, in your example "If B is started and A is not running, start A"

When you add the `WantedBy=multi-user.target` you are now telling the system that the services must be started when the system is initialising `multi-user.target`, presumably this means once you added it you were letting the system start the services instead of starting them manually?

I'm not sure why this doesn't work in version 220, it might be worth trying 222. I'll dig out a VM and try your services when I get a chance.

Comment: I asked on systemd-devel, the fact that it was working in 219 was a bug. The intended behavior is that failed dependencies do *NOT* get restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I spent days on this, trying to get it to work the "systemd" way, but gave up in frustration and wrote a wrapper script to manage dependencies and failures.  Each child service is a normal systemd service, with no "Requires" or "PartOf" or any hooks to other services.

My top level service file looks like this:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=REQUIRES=foo.service bar.service
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/systemctl start $REQUIRES
ExecStart=@PREFIX@/bin/top-service.sh $REQUIRES
ExecStop=/usr/bin/systemctl      stop $REQUIRES
```

So far, so good. The `top.service` file controls `foo.service` and `bar.service`.  Starting `top` starts `foo` and `bar`, and stopping `top` stops `foo` and `bar`. The final ingredient is my `top-service.sh` script which monitors the services for failure:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This monitors REQUIRES services. If any service stops, all of the services are stopped and this script ends.

REQUIRES="$@"

if [ "$REQUIRES" == "" ]
then
  echo "ERROR: no services listed"
  exit 1
fi

echo "INFO: watching services: ${REQUIRES}"

end=0
while [[ $end == 0 ]]
do
  s=$(systemctl is-active ${REQUIRES} )
  if echo $s | egrep '^(active ?)+$' > /dev/null
  then
    # $s has embedded newlines, but echo $s seems to get rid of them, while echo "$s" keeps them.
    # echo INFO: All active, $s
    end=0
  else
    echo "WARN: ${REQUIRES}"
    echo WARN: $s
  fi

  if [[ $s == *"failed"* ]] || [[ $s == *"unknown"* ]]
  then
    echo "WARN: At least one service is failed or unknown, ending service"
    end=1
  else
    sleep 1
  fi
done

echo "INFO: done watching services, stopping: ${REQUIRES}"
systemctl stop ${REQUIRES}
echo "INFO: stopped: ${REQUIRES}"
exit 1
```

Comment: `REQUIRES="$@"` is innately buggy code -- you're collapsing an array into a string, discarding the original boundaries between items, so the argument created by, ie. `set -- "argument one" "argument two"` becomes identical to `set -- "argument" "one" "argument" "two"`. `requires=( "$@" )` would keep the original data, thus being safely expandable as `systemctl is-active "${requires[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1312#issuecomment-1139234399

> Out of interest, would the new `Upholds=`, introduced in commit [0bc488c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/0bc488c99ab2ed3464237607e381f4d72cd321d5) of PR #19322, be something that would help here?
>
> Specifically, suppose `b.service` is configured with `Wants=a.service` and `After=a.service` and `Restart=on-failure`. Then `a.service` times out while starting so that `b.service` also then fails with `b.service/start failed with result 'dependency'`. Next, `a.service` succeeds after being restarted, but `b.service` never starts because, apparently, dependency failures are not considered as triggers by the `Restart=on-failure` mode.
>
> (This is exactly the situation reported in the already-linked Stack Exchange [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213185/restarting-systemd-service-on-dependency-failure) for which one of the answer comments also links back to this issue.)
>
> Having bumped into this long-standing issue, I'm wondering if the `Upholds=` directive would have an effect if it was specified such that `a.service` was configured with `Upholds=b.service`? Would that cause `b.service` to be started when `a.service` finally comes up?

and if you can upgrade systemd to [`v254`](https://lwn.net/Articles/939511/) also [try out](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1312#issuecomment-1711831769) [`RestartMode=direct`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/27584): https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#RestartMode=

Answer (score -1):

Not answer to this. 
But somebody might need this (because as this page shows up in search):

should be

```
[Service]
 Restart=always
 RestartSec=3
```

https://jonarcher.info/2015/08/ensure-systemd-services-restart-on-failure/

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. This is not about restarting a single unhealthy service, but about how systemd behaves when a defendant service fails.